# Wildfly to use hashed password in the pooled-connection-factory

Tags: jboss, wildfly, netty, wildfly-10

I am following [this](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-jms/connecting-to-an-external-wildfly-jms-server/#remotejms) guide to make remote JMS listener, it works fine.
I need to use the hashed password value in the pooled-connection-factory.
But I don't want to use the plain password in the password param, I tried with hashed password value it is not allowing to connect.

Is there any way to use the management user encrypted password ?

Exception:

> org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException:
> javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: AMQ229031: Unable to validate user
> from /127.0.0.1:61662. Username: testuser; SSL certificate subject DN:

**Code:**

```
<pooled-connection-factory name="remote-artemis" entries="java:/jms/remoteCF" connectors="remote-artemis" user="testuser" password="16b322f4cfe1023d67ecc13d626cb32c"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using elytron you can use:

https://wildfly-security.github.io/wildfly-elytron/blog/wildfly-encrypted-expressions/

For older WildFly there is the vault, which is removed now:

https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/networking-and-servers/9781784392413/11/ch11lvl1sec97/securing-and-protecting-passwords-using-a-vault

Comment: I am using wildfly 24.

Comment: how is pooled connection security similar/different/related to the security domain defined on the subsystem=messaging-activemq ?